# Netty Channel fail when write and flush too many and too fast

Tags: java, netty

When I write a producer to publish message to my server. I've seen this:

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:384)
at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:447)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've searched all around and was told that because of channel is closed.
But, in my code. I'm just close my channel when my channel pool destroy the channel. 
Here my code:

```
public static class ChannelFactory implements PoolableObjectFactory<Channel> {

    private final Bootstrap bootstrap;
    private String host;
    private int port;

    public ChannelFactory(Bootstrap bootstrap, String host, int port) {
        this.bootstrap = bootstrap;
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public Channel makeObject() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Create new channel!!!");
        bootstrap.validate();
        return bootstrap.connect(host, port).channel();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyObject(Channel channel) throws Exception {
        ChannelFuture close = channel.close();
        if (close.isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println(channel + " close successfully");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateObject(Channel channel) {
        System.out.println("Validate object");
        return (channel.isOpen());
    }

    @Override
    public void activateObject(Channel channel) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(channel + " is activated");
    }

    @Override
    public void passivateObject(Channel channel) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(channel + " is passivated");
    }

    /**
     * @return the host
     */
    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    /**
     * @param host the host to set
     * @return
     */
    public ChannelFactory setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the port
     */
    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    /**
     * @param port the port to set
     * @return
     */
    public ChannelFactory setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        return this;
    }

}
```

And here is my Runner:

```
public static class Runner implements Runnable {

    private Channel channel;
    private ButtyMessage message;
    private MyChannelPool channelPool;

    public Runner(MyChannelPool channelPool, Channel channel, ButtyMessage message) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.message = message;
        this.channelPool = channelPool;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        channel.writeAndFlush(message.content()).syncUninterruptibly().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                channelPool.returnObject(future.channel());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final String host = "127.0.0.1";
    final int port = 8080;
    int jobSize = 100;
    int jobNumber = 10000;
    final Bootstrap b = func(host, port);

    final MyChannelPool channelPool = new MyChannelPool(new ChannelFactory(b, host, port));

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < jobNumber; i++) {
        try {
            threadPool.execute(new Runner(channelPool, channelPool.borrowObject(), new ButtyMessage()));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("ex = " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

With `ButtyMessage` extends `ByteBufHolder`. 
In my Runner class, if I sleep(10) after `writeAndFlush` it run quite OK. But I don't want to reply on sleep. So I use `ChannelFutureListener`, but the result is bad. If I send about 1000 to 10.000 messages, it will crash and throw exception above. Is there any way to avoid this? 

Thanks all. 
Sorry for my bad explain and my English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues that could explain this. Most of them are related to wrong usage of asynchronous operations and future usage.

- I don't know if it could be in link with your issue but, if you really want to print when the channel is really closed, you have to wait on the future, since the future on `close()` (or any other operations) immediately returns, without waiting for the real close. Therefore your test `if (close.isSuccess())` shall be always false.

  ```
  public void destroyObject(final Channel channel) throws Exception {
     channel.close().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture close) {
          if (close.isSuccess()) {
             System.out.println(channel + " close successfully");
          }
        }
     });
  }
  ```

However, as I suppose it is only for debug purpose, it is not mandatory.

- Another one: you send back to your pool a channel that is not already connected (which could explain your sleep(10) maybe?). You have to wait on the `connect()`.

  ```
  public Channel makeObject() throws Exception {
     System.out.println("Create new channel!!!");
     //bootstrap.validate(); // this is implicitely called in connect()
     ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(host, port).awaitUninterruptibly();
     if (future.isSuccess()) {
       return future.channel();
     } else {
       // do what you need to do when the connection is not done
     }
  }
  ```
- third one: validation of a connected channel might be better using `isActive()`:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean validateObject(Channel channel) {
      System.out.println("Validate object");
      return channel.isActive(); // instead of isOpen()
  }
  ```
- fourth one: in your runner, you wrongly await on the future while you should not. You can remove your `syncUninterruptibly()` and let the rest as is.

  ```
  @Override
  public void run() {
     Channel.writeAndFlush(message.content()).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
       @Override
       public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
          channelPool.returnObject(future.channel());
       }
     });
  }
  ```
- And finally, I suppose you know your test is completely sequential (1 thread in your pool), such that each client will reuse over and over the very same channel?

Could you try to change the 4 points to see if it corrects your issue?

---

**EDIT:** after requester comment

For `syncUntinterruptibly()`, I did not read carefully. If you want to block on write, then you don't need the extra `addListener` since the future is done once the sync is over. So you can directly call your `channelPool.returnObject` as next command just after your sync.

So you should write it this way, simpler.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
       Channel.writeAndFlush(message.content()).syncUntinterruptibly();
       channelPool.returnObject(future.channel());
    }
```

For `fireChannelActive`, it will be called as soon as the connect finished (so from `makeObject`, sometime in the future). Moreover, once disconnected (as you did have notice in your exception), the channel is no more usable and must be recreated from zero. So I would suggest to use isActive however, such that, if not active, it will be removed using destroyObject...

Take a look at the channel state model [here](http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#wiki-h4-19).

Comment: Thank for your help :). It gave me a lot of idea. But the issue till not solved. In my opinion, all thing in Netty is async. So I put `channel.writeAndFlush(message.content()).syncUninterruptibly()`  <br/>
And about the `channel.isActive()`, when first time, the channel is not active because noone call `fireChannelActive`, so, `channel` will not _active_, beside that, `isOpen` may right for this case.  <br/>
I'm trying to find the way. Regards.

Comment: I update my answear accordingly. I agree that I read too quickly for the `sync` part. However, for the `isOpen` part, I suggest you to change it to `isActive`. Hoping this will help you a bit...

Also one extra question: how much client were able to send a message to the server before you get this error?

Comment: Sorry, my time zone :) It was over 1AM so I'm fall as sleep.
I may try and return the result for you as soon as possible :). Thank.

Comment: Dear @Frederic , I've solved my problem :D
I suppose that my approach having some problem that I can track or handle (I think when I write in the same Channel, the write and flush handler by thread has problem cause the socket fail (the reason cause at first I just use a single thread)). So, I'm retry, delete all my code and try to use the _ChannelPool_ supported by netty. It's workd!!!
And i'm succeed with that. I'm going to post my code with solution later. (It's about 12AM here, and I'm feel really tire now :) )
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: And, I more thing. I think we just don't rely on _sync_ of netty. Use _CountDownLatch_ or something similar is a good choice. Async still async :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found a solution for myself. But, I'm still think about another solution. (this solution is exactly copy from 4.0.28 netty release note)

```
final String host = "127.0.0.1";
    final int port = 8080;
    int jobNumber = 100000;
    final EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup(100);

    ChannelPoolMap<InetSocketAddress, MyChannelPool> poolMap = new AbstractChannelPoolMap<InetSocketAddress, MyChannelPool>() {

        @Override
        protected MyChannelPool newPool(InetSocketAddress key) {
            Bootstrap bootstrap = func(group, key.getHostName(), key.getPort());
            return new MyChannelPool(bootstrap, new _AbstractChannelPoolHandler());
        }
    };

    ChannelPoolMap<InetSocketAddress, FixedChannelPool> poolMap1 = new AbstractChannelPoolMap<InetSocketAddress, FixedChannelPool>() {

        @Override
        protected FixedChannelPool newPool(InetSocketAddress key) {
            Bootstrap bootstrap = func(group, key.getHostName(), key.getPort());
            return new FixedChannelPool(bootstrap, new _AbstractChannelPoolHandler(), 10);
        }
    };

    final ChannelPool myChannelPool = poolMap.get(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(jobNumber);

    for (int i = 0; i < jobNumber; i++) {
        final int counter = i;
        final Future<Channel> future = myChannelPool.acquire();
        future.addListener(new FutureListener<Channel>() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(Future<Channel> f) {
                if (f.isSuccess()) {
                    Channel ch = f.getNow();
                    // Do somethings
                    ch.writeAndFlush(new ButtyMessage().content()).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                                System.out.println("counter = " + counter);
                                System.out.println("future = " + future.channel());
                                latch.countDown();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    // Release back to pool
                    myChannelPool.release(ch);

                } else {
                    System.out.println(f.cause().getMessage());
                    f.cause().printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    try {
        latch.await();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("ex = " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

As you can see, I use `SimpleChannelPool` and `FixedChannelPool` (an implementation of `SimpleChannelPool` provided by netty). 
What it can do:
`SimpleChannelPool`: open channels as much as it need ---> if you has 100.000 msg -> cuz error, of course. Many socket  open, then IOExeption: Too many file open occur. (is that really pool? Create as much as possible and throw exception? I don't call this is pooling) 
`FixedChannelPool`: not work in my case (Still study why? =)) Sorry for my stupidness)
Indeed, I want to use ObjectPool instead. And I may post it as soon as when I finish. Tks @Frederic Brégier for helping me so much!